# can anyone tell me whats wrong in my code of binary search tree insertion

Tags: search, data-structures, binary

i am trying to insert elements in binary search tree , without recursion (but this code is just inserting the root element and no other elements ) .i don't know whats wrong , this code should work , but its not , i am not good with reccursion and every code on internet was with recursion for inserting elements in the binary search tree. can anyone tell me , whats wrong and how should i correct it??
here is the code

```
<#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
  int data;
  node *left;
  node *right;
}*root=NULL;
void insert(int data)
{   node* temp=new node;

  node *ptr=root;
  temp->data=data;
  temp->left=NULL;
  temp->right=NULL;
  if(ptr==NULL)
    {
      root=temp;

    }
  else
    {
      while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
          if(data<=(ptr->data))     
            {ptr=ptr->left;}
          else{
            ptr=ptr->right;
          }
        }//while loop ends here so that i get the ptr to be

      ptr=temp;
    }
}
void disp(node* ptr)
{
  if(ptr==NULL)
    return ;
  disp(ptr->left);
  cout<<ptr->data<<endl;
  disp(ptr->right);
}


int main()
{   
  insert(10);
  insert(11);
  insert(23);
  disp(root);

}
```

Comment: i am sorry the code starts form the include part in the question , i am new to the stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never write in you tree, only in local var ptr. In your code, you should insert temp when you find a NULL child.

```
void insert(int data)
{
  node* temp=new node;
  node *ptr=root;
  temp->data=data;
  temp->left=NULL;
  temp->right=NULL;
  if(ptr==NULL)
    {
      root=temp;        
    }
  else
    {
      while(1)
        {
          if(data<=(ptr->data)) {
            if(ptr->left) ptr=ptr->left;
            else {ptr->left=temp; break;}
          }
          else{
            if(ptr->right) ptr=ptr->right;
            else {ptr->right=temp; break;}
          }
        }//while loop ends here so that i get the ptr to be         
    }
}
```